# timer_create and timer_settime generating segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, posix

I am creating a timer. The structure is:

```
struct my_timer
{
  unsigned int ip_address;
  timer_t timer;
};
```

Now `ip_address` is initialized.

After that when I try to create timer via "timer_create", it's throwing segmentation fault .

If I don't initialize `ip_address` before and then create the timer then timer is getting created successfully.

Can anyone help here, as to why its happening?

Basically I want `ip_address` to find which timer has to be stopped later.

Comment: I have no clue. Show more code? My only (farfetched) hunch is that you might be using a union instead of a struct there.

Comment: My hunch is that you're not passing the right arguments to `timer_create`. Show us the code. The question is unanswerable in its current form...

Comment: hi , i got around the seg fault at timer_create by initializing ip_address later on ...but problem is now coming at stop timer when i try to do timer_settime .

Comment: so this proves that there is no problem in arguments in timer_create .. now can anyone help me here to get around seg fault at timer_settime (i am using ip_address to find which timer to stop , ip_address initializtion can't be avoided before stopping the timer)

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html), `timer_create(2)` does not take any sort of argument containing an IP address, nor a structure containing a `timer_t` plus a user-specified other part.

Do you have compiler warnings enabled?  I imagine you are simply calling these functions with inappropriate arguments, but without seeing your code there's no way to know for sure.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your replies .. I finally got teh problem solved , in the timer_settime to stop the timer I was mistakenly passing the timer id , instead of pointer to the timer id .... its working fine now ... :)

Comment: I don't understand.  The documentation for timer_settime says it takes a timer_t as its first argument.  Are you saying that you now pass a timer_t* and it works better than passing a timer_t?  If so, is your system non-standard or has documentation that differs in this regard from the top hits for timer_settime on Google?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here, the declaration for "stop_timer" function is                                            stop_timer(timer_t *timerid).                                     stop_timer function is getting the pointer to a timer id , but in that function I was wrongly sending the timer id itself. In the stop_timer I am using timer_settime(*timerid , 0 , &its , NULL). So this means that effectively I am sending the timer_t value only in timer_settime.

Comment: I see.  Shouldn't your compiler have complained loudly about this obvious error?  Are your compiler's warnings not enabled?